# Divide ip network into 4 subnets

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, subnet

I've got a task:

> Divide the IP network 150.200.0.0 with the network mask of
>   255.255.0.0(/16) into 4 subnets.

I need to fill up a table, I googled it and filled it up like this, not sure if it is correct or not. Can you help me with this?

```html
+------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| Bits | Subnet adress | Subnet mask | Computer address range | Broadcast address |
+------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+
| ?    |  150.200.16.0 | 255.255.0.0 | 17-31                  |      150.200.16.0 |
| ?    |  150.200.32.0 | 255.255.0.0 | 33-47                  |      150.200.32.0 |
| ?    |  150.200.48.0 | 255.255.0.0 | 47-63                  |      150.200.48.0 |
| ?    |  150.200.64.0 | 255.255.0.0 | 65-79                  |      150.200.64.0 |
+------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is the correctly filled table. We divide 255/4 = 64 (this is a step in subnet addresses). Subnet mask 255.555.0.0 in binary = 11111111.11111111.00000000.00000000. We add 11 to third octet if we divide into 4 subnets, 111 for 8 subnets, etc. So 11111111.11111111.11000000.00000000 = 255.255.192.0.

```html
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| Bits | Subnet adress |  Subnet mask  |     Computer address range      | Broadcast address |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
|   00 |   150.200.0.0 | 255.255.192.0 | 150.200.0.1 - 150.200.63.254    |    150.200.63.255 |
|   01 |  150.200.64.0 | 255.255.192.0 | 150.200.64.1 - 150.200.127.254  |   150.200.127.255 |
|   10 | 150.200.128.0 | 255.255.192.0 | 150.200.128.1 - 150.200.191.254 |   150.200.191.255 |
|   11 | 150.200.192.0 | 255.255.192.0 | 150.200.192.1 - 150.200.255.254 |   150.200.255.255 |
+------+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just make the segments like that, you need to modify the subnet mask, which in this case, for dividing the network into 4 would be a 255.255.192.0.

First segment would be 150.200.0.1 to 150.200.63.254 with broadcast 150.200.63.255

Comment: Please check your broadcast address. I think it's supposed to be `150.200.63.255`